# Надо синонимизировать [спрайт]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать [sprite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprite) (74 вопроса) -> [спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) (12 вопросов).

Comment: А почему бы и нет.

Comment: mountain dew туда же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готово:

```
updating post history, 77 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 74 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 71 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'sprite': [sprite] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 83
tag remapping of [спрайт] and [sprite] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym sprite -> спрайт was approved!
```